# Prove that this subgroup is normal in $G$ where $G$ is a subgroup of $GL(2,\Bbb{F}$).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose that we have 2 subgroups  of $GL(2,\Bbb{F}$).

$G$ that contains matrices of the form:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
        a & b \\
        0 & c  \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$ where $a,b \in \Bbb{F}$.

And $H$ that contains matrices of the form:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & b \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$ where $b \in \Bbb{F}$.

Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup in $G$.

**My attempt:**

Let $A$ be a matrix in $G$. For every matrix $B$ in $H$, we have:

$ABA^{-1}$ = $$\left(\begin{matrix}
        ac & a^2b \\
        0 & ac  \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

$det(ABA^{-1})$ = $det(A)$ $det(B)$ $det(A^{-1})$ = $det(A)det(A^{-1})$ = $1$.

And $det(ABA^{-1})$= $(ac)^2$, so $(ac)^2$ = $1$ which means that $ac$ = $ \pm 1$ and not only $1$. so how can we conclude that $ABA^{-1}$ $\in$ $H$?

Comment: Check your $A^{-1}$ again

Comment: Two comments: A) The $b$ parameters in $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily equal. B) You made an error in calculating $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh, right! I made a mistake in calculating $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative approach to proving a subgroup is normal is to prove
that it's a kernel of some homomorphism. How about
$$\pmatrix{a&b\\0&c}\mapsto\pmatrix{a&0\\0&c}?$$
Is this a homomorphism? If so, what's its kernel?

Comment: A better approach! An even simpler homomorphism would be to map that matrix $\mapsto a$. Oops. That doesn't work. I have used $SL_2$ too often as of late. :-)

Comment: Ummm I'm not familiar with this method. But what should be the homomorphism's domain and codomain to apply this approach?

Comment: The domain would be $G$ of course; as for the codomain, well that has to be a suitable matrix group....

Comment: But finding such a homomorphism is not easy. I think it needs a lot of practice. So we can apply this to other questions by taking our $G$ as a domain, but we can take any codomain?